# How to determine who started a process?

Tags: linux, process

every few minutes I found this process running

```
 root      949062  100  0.0  37204  1488 ?        R<   05:14   0:51 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/clamdscan --quiet --no-summary /etc/passwd
```

It's using 100% cpu. I kill it , and after some time I see it again .
How can I determine who is running this process ?

Comment: Clam is an antivirus typically used in email servers. It looks like you have it enabled in Cpanel.

Comment: when speaking of process and others it's always a good idea to tell us which linux distro you're using and which version you're running.

Comment: It is being run by `root`. Presumably from a cronjob but for more details you will have to tell us your operating system, whether you are the administrator, whether this is a remote machine administered by someone else etc.

Comment: I have CLOUDLINUX 6.5 x86_64 with cPanel. clamav is installed however its usage is disabled for customers . The process is constantly checking this  /etc/passwd and overloading the cpu. I do not understand WHO is starting the process.

Comment: I am the administrator, in root cronjob (crontab -e) there is no clamd row.

Comment: I know the process is root, I would know WHO is starting this root process.

Comment: Checking the parent process id might reveal some more info. Try running `pstree`

Comment: If you are feeling adventurous, `cd /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin;mv clamdscan clamdscan.old` That will stop it from running at all, but if it is already meant to be disabled, then you shouldn't notice any adverse affects.

Comment: Try ps -axf.I guess you can find the parent of that process.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to replace the process by a "wrapper" script.

```
 # cd /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/
 # cp -p clamdscan clamdscan.orig 
 # cat >clamdscan <<eof
 #!/bin/bash 
 echo ==================== >>/tmp/clamscan.log
 date  >>/tmp/clamscan.log
 id    >>/tmp/clamscan.log
 ps -fp $PPID   >>/tmp/clamscan.log
 tty   >>/tmp/clamscan.log
 pstree -Ap >> /tmp/clamscan.log 
 exec $0.orig $*
 eof
```

That way each each call of clamscan will log some information. 
The commands are just to illustrate that you may change it at your convenience. 
Of course you should not let it run too long if you don't want to have a full /tmp directory.

To abort simply do:

```
 # cd /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/
 # mv clamdscan.orig clamdscan
```